# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Evaluate

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx$