# How to prove $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx=f(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits

I need help to prove this in real analysis. I think it uses IMVT, but not sure how to do it.

> Let $f(x)$ be a real valued continuous function on $[0,1]$. Show that
>   $$
> \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx=f(1)
> $$

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: A few similar questions: [For $f$ continuous, show $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx = f(1)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/455193),
[Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1f(x)g(x^n)dx=f(1)\int_0^1\frac{g(x)}{x}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/238433),
[Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/225550)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1026197/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$. Also
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x\in(1-\delta,1],\text{there is } |f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon 
$$

\begin{align}
\left|(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|&=
\left|\int_{0}^{1-\delta} (n+1)x^nf(x)dx+\int_{1-\delta}^{1} (n+1)x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|
\\
&=\left|f(t_1) \int_{0}^{1-\delta} (n+1)x^ndx+f(t_2)\int_{1-\delta}^{1} (n+1)x^ndx-f(1)\right| \hspace{5 mm}  
\\ &\hspace{10 mm}(t_1\in(0,1-\delta),t_2\in(1-\delta,1) \text{ and by IMVT})
\\
&=\left|f(t_1)(1-\delta)^{n+1}+f(t_2)(1-(1-\delta)^{n+1})-f(1)\right|
\\
&\leqslant 2M(1-\delta)^{n+1}+|f(t_2)-f(1)|
\\&<2M(1-\delta)^{n+1}+\epsilon
\end{align}
So
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|\leqslant \varlimsup\limits_{n\to\infty}2M(1-\delta)^{n+1}+\epsilon=\epsilon
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary small
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|=0 \hspace{5 mm} \text{and}\hspace{5 mm} \varliminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|=0 
$$

So 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx-f(1)\right|=0\hspace{5 mm} \text{or} \hspace{5 mm}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx=f(1)
$$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is continuous on a closed interval, so it is bounded, $-M<f(x)<M$ for some $M$.
For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ for which $f(1)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(1)+\epsilon$ whenever $x>1-\delta$.
$|(n+1)\int_0^{1-\delta}x^nf(x)dx|\leq(n+1)\int_0^{1-\delta}x^nMdx=M(1-\delta)^{n+1}\to0$
Now show that $(n+1)\int_{1-\delta}^1x^nf(x)dx$ approaches a number within $\epsilon$ of $f(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a much less rigorous process. For the problem
\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx=f(1)
\end{align}
let $f(x)$ be a fuction that can be expanded in a power series, $f(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_{k} \, x^{k}$, that satisfies  a real valued continuous function on [0,1] then
\begin{align}
L &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} \, \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1) \, \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+k} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} \, \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n+1}{n+k+1} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} \, \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{1 + \frac{k+1}{n}} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} = f(1)
\end{align}

Comment: $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable. So you can not use Taylor series.