# Finding limits with integral sign

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function whose derivative is continuous. Then, find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1) \int_{0}^1 \! x^n f(x) dx
$$
I know how to compute limits of integration using l hospital rule. In this problem, I am not to proceed with the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563666/to-evaluate-limit-lim-n-to-infty-n1-int-01xnfxdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Use integration by parts and the fact that $|f'(x)|\le M$ (for some constant $M$) on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I got this after using by part. \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[\int_{0}^{1} f(x) x^{n+1}dx]-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[\int_{0}^{1} f'(x) x^{n+1}dx]. But I am not able to get the fact that you are talking about. Is M is Maximum between the limits of integration.

Comment: The first term does not have an integral in it! Yes, you're right about $M$; just give an upper bound for  the second term and show it goes to $0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks I got your explanation. You explained nicely.

Comment: Glad to help. Enjoy learning mathematics!