Calculate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n\int _0^1x^n\sqrt{1+x^2}\,{\rm d}x\right)$
It can be solved by using First mean value theorem for definite integrals, but I have no idea about the exact answer, only have a answer range.
There is a similar question:
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\int _0^1x^n\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$
By using First mean value theorem for definite integrals, it turns into:
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt{1+ξ^2}\int _0^1\:x^ndx$
Because $\int _0^1\:x^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}$→0, $1<\sqrt{1+ξ^2}<\sqrt{2}$
so the original formula=0.

First, change $x \mapsto 1 - x$ and then Laplace’s Method.

This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1563666/42969. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1303672/42969 and the linked questions.
